# Python: Iterating through multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I've 3 lists, each of them contains dictionaries. I would get the values for certain keys and want to save the result from the min-Operation of this values. The following code gives a error: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools


humidity = [{'high': 90, 'middle': 50, 'low': 10}, {'high': 75, 'middle': 40, 'low': 5} ]

temperature =[{'warm': 35, 'normal': 20, 'cold': 5 }, {'warm': 40, 'normal': 18, 'cold': 10 }]

wind = [{'breeze': 25, 'gale': 100}, {'breeze': 20, 'gale': 90}]

results=[]
for h, t, w in itertools.izip(humidity, temperature, wind):

  results.append(np.fmin (humidity[h]['high'], np.fmin( temperature[t]['normal'], wind[w]['breeze']) ) )
```

But if i wrote in the console(Spyder,python 2.7):

```
 result = np.fmin (humidity[0]['high'], np.fmin( temperature[0]['normal'], wind[0]['breeze']) )
```

I get 20 and it's true. But why can I not iterate over the whole dictionaries? What is wrong?

Thank you very much for your answers/ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference your `h,t,w` variables instead of the original lists

```
results.append(np.fmin (h['high'], np.fmin( t['normal'], w['breeze']) ) )
```

as `h,t,w` are dictionaries unpacked from your zip, not `int`s so you can't use them to index a list

Visiually, `humidity[h]['high']` looks like

```
humidity[{'high': 90, 'middle': 50, 'low': 10}]['high']
```

Which does not make sense syntactically

Comment: thank you! it just works! But how can you explain, why it works in the console, if i give integer values? I mean in case 2 like humidity[0]['high']

Comment: @lara sure. when you type `h,t,w in itertools...`, you are *unpacking* the tuple that gets zipped by the `itertools.izip`. If you are unfamiliar with it read the description of what it does. If you didn't want to have to zip everything together, you could simply do `for index,_ in enumerate(humidity):` and then access each list by `humidity[index][key] .... temperature[index][key] ....` etc, because range will return numbers up to the length of the list you pass it. This of course is based on the assumption that wind, temperature, and humidity are always the same length.

Comment: thanks C.B. ;) this single error costs me a lot of time!